# Air sub applications

Tags: installation, air

Hi Is it possible for an Adobe Air application to install, upgrade and execute other Adobe-Air files.

The basic use case is for a launcher application.  It launches and manages other applications at user request, however doesn't need to install the runtimes until such a point as the user intends to execute it.

**EDIT:**
A good starting point may be in this question [AIR App that Loads and Runs Existing AIR swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294091/air-app-that-loads-and-runs-existing-air-swf)

**EDIT**
I'm going to cross post this to flexcoders though I'm not really happy with doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AIR 2.0, when installed with the extended desktop profile (native installers) can use the **NativeProcess** class to control any application on the system, monitor its commandline feedback, and terminate as needed. Extremely basic example below:

```
import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;

if (NativeProcess.isSupported) {
    var npsi:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
    var processpath:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("MyApplication.whatever");
    var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();

    npsi.executable = processpath;
    process.start(npsi);
}
```

You should additionally be monitoring specific IO events, error events, the exit event, and you can also provide command line arguments in the **NativeProcessStartupInfo** object. As for installing, that might be tricker, because AIR has a graphical installation process and I haven't experimented with it that much, but it should be able to run an installer.

AIR applications can also provide a custom upgrade interface; however, I don't think another AIR application can manage that task. Given that AIR apps upgrade themselves fairly seamlessly, that could be left as is.

Comment: Sorry I was away when this reply came in. I think this is a useful answer sorry I didn't get to accept it.

Comment: No worries, glad it was of use :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [File.openWithDefaultApplication()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html?allClasses=1#openWithDefaultApplication())?