# How to call a specific client side program in Flash player controlled by Actionscript?

Tags: flash, web-applications, actionscript

Or is it possible in Flash?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible from a browser.

Comment: @wamp tell us what you want to do - which program are you trying to call?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Air is the only means of accessing client side applications from ActionScript.

See my answer here: [Air sub applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275746/air-sub-applications/3409060#3409060)

Comment: Can I automate the installation of an independant programe with Air,like **flash media live encoder**?

Comment: Air is able to provide command line parameters and tell a process to run. At that point, it can monitor output, or close the process. If you can get that to install with that level of control, then yes. It cannot control GUI interactions, so it is up to the installer whether it can be run in a silent mode. Though I believe the user will be presented with any GUI options if they are spawned, so it can definitely start the sequence of events needed to install something.

Comment: But I need to get the full path to that programe to call it,right?How can I retrieve it programatically with air?

Comment: You can either have the user browse for and select it using a File object or similarly using the File object, retrieve the path to the applications directory and resolve the remainder relatively.

Comment: Just to keep everything clear, Air generates standalone applications and does not run in the browser.